# how do you make np.dot give an exact integer answer

Tags: numpy

I am dotting to arrays with large integer values and I need an integer answer.
if I do nothing ie

```
a.dot(b)
```

My solution is to use :

```
np.array(a.dot(b),dtype = np.uint64)
```

This works but seems very clunky!
Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Not really, unless you implement the functionality from more basic functions. `dot` will always return a float type as far as I can tell. You can use `ndarray.astype` instead.

Comment: Show a sample array and indicate your version of numpy please. I am unable to reproduce your issue with np version 1.13.1.

Comment: set the dtypes of `a` and `b` to `int`

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that if you specify that the two arrays are large integers then you get a large integer the following works.

```
import numpy as np
b = 2**np.arange(49, dtype = np.uint64)[::-1]
a = np.zeros(49,dtype = np.uint64)
a[0] = 1
c = a.dot(b)
print (c,type(c))
```

Incidentally this is my method of converting an array of ones and zeros into an integer representation